# Event to be triggered at a configurable time in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, polling

I am working on a project which has a table "Games" with columns ID, Name, Start-time, End-time. Whenever an item is added to the table, and the end-time is reached, I want to trigger an event (SNS notification, but I can work my way around with anything else). The current implementation polls the table to check what "games" have expired and generates the event. Is there a technique to avoid polling, like SQSs, SWFs which I can use. The problem with the current approach is the polling the DB is costing me too much money since the complete infra is on cloud.

Comment: How do you currently poll the DynamoDB table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS DynamoDB is a perfect suit for this. You can set the record to Auto-Expire with a TTL attribute and the record will be removed.

If you want to extend the time of auto expiry, you can update the ttl attribute of the record and it will get extended.

**Time to Live on DynamoDB:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html

You can configure a lambda to capture the deleted record and do whatever you want to do from there.

**DynamoDB Streams:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

It is all event-based and zero polling.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you configure the TTL on a per-record basis? Like OP's end-time column?

Comment: Yes. TTL is based on per record.

Comment: I really want this to work, but the DDB docs say "DynamoDB typically deletes expired items within 48 hours of expiration." Does this mean that the expiration event happens within 48 hours of the time you set? Or does the expiration event happen within 0.25 seconds of the set time, and then there is a separate deletion process which can take a long time?

Comment: That is correct. AWS takes up to 48 hours to delete those records depending upon the workload on the given table. If you want to do precise deletion you can create CloudWatch events and handle that in Lambda.

Comment: Clouwdwatch event are on aservice level rather than record. How would you use cloudwatch event where TTL is different for each record?

Comment: Don’t confuse cloudwatch event bus event with dynamodb. DynamoDB has built in capability to delete records at a certain configured time in one of its attributes.